# Bind onclick to nodes in a loop

Tags: javascript

I have a function add_the_handler that binds an onclick event to each node. The following example prints `"3"` in every alert window, when I click on any node:

```
var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {

var i;
    for (i=0; i< nodes.length; i+=1) {

        nodes[i].onclick = function (e) {
            alert(i);    
        };
    }
};
```

fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/D886E/3/

Why doesn´t the nodes print the different values 1,2,3 in the alert windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D886E/15/). Basically you need a function clojure to handle the attaching of the listeners to the appropriate index in the loop

```
var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
        (function (i) {
            nodes[i].onclick = function (e) {
                alert(i);
            };

        })(i);
    }
};

pnodes = document.getElementsByClassName("node");

add_the_handlers(pnodes);
```